# if else in AlertDialog is not working Android kotlin

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I am trying to edit and update already saved ATM card details. I am using Alert Dialog with a Layout to edit the card details. Here, the user after filling the details clicks on positive(update) button the Alert Dialog will not be closed instead it validates the user Input.

But the problem is, once users enters the Card Holder Name(or any other details) and click on update (Positive button) it still show the same toast as "Card Holder Field is Blank". It seems like the details are not updating with latest details. Please help me in resolving the issue.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    val card: Cards = cards[p1]


    p0.BankName.text = card.bankName
    p0.CVV.text = card.cardCVV
    p0.CardHolderName.text = card.cardHolderName
    p0.Expire.text = card.validity
    p0.CardNumber.text = card.cardNumber

    p0.optionsMenu.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        val popupMenu = PopupMenu(mContext, p0.optionsMenu)
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.option_menu)
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.mnu_item_Edit -> {
                    var message: String = "Details Updated"
                    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update1, null)

                    var builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                        .setTitle("Update Card details")
                        .setView(view)
                        .setPositiveButton("Update", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which -> })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which -> })
                    val alert = builder.create()
                    alert.show()


                    alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                        val isUpdate: Boolean = MainActivity.dbHander.editCard(
                            card.cardID.toString(),
                            view.uBankName.text.toString(),
                            view.uCardNumber.text.toString(),
                            view.uCardCVV.text.toString(),
                            view.uCardHolder.text.toString(),
                            view.uCardValidity.text.toString()
                        )

                        if (isUpdate == true) {

                            cards[p1].bankName = view.uBankName.text.toString()
                            cards[p1].cardHolderName = view.uCardHolder.text.toString()
                            cards[p1].cardNumber = view.uCardNumber.text.toString()
                            cards[p1].cardCVV = view.uCardCVV.text.toString()
                            cards[p1].validity = view.uCardValidity.text.toString()
                            notifyDataSetChanged()
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            alert.dismiss()
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            popupMenu.show()
        }
    })

}
```

I am validating the user inputs by below method

```
fun editCard(
    cardId: String,
    bankName: String,
    cardHolderName: String,
    cardCVV: String,
    validity: String,
    cardNumber: String
): Boolean {

    var result: Boolean = false

    if (bankName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(toast, "Bank Name should not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    } else if (cardHolderName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(toast, "Card Holder Name should not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else if (cardNumber.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(toast, "Card number should not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else if (cardNumber.length != 16) {
        Toast.makeText(toast, "Card number 16 digits", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else if (validity.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(toast, "Card validity should not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    } else if (cardCVV.isNullOrEmpty()) {

        Toast.makeText(toast, "CVV should not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    } else if (cardCVV.length != 3) {
        Toast.makeText(toast, "Must have 3 digits", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    } else {
        //will do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you receive any another answer try to Clean, Rebuild project and Restart android studio

Comment: your code seems not completed. You are not returning any `boolean` value in `editCard` function.